# Add missing value in column according to value of previous or next row in R

Tags: r, imputation

I have some longitudinal data and need to impute missing values by some rules:

1. If a person’s first follow-up data is missing, then add the value of the next row;
2. If a person's non-first follow-up data is missing, then add the value of the previous row;
3. If multiple consecutive follow-up data are missing, then add the value of the previous non-missing row.

Here is an example,

```r
dat<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),b6=c(NA,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,NA,3,NA,NA,5,5,5,5,3,NA,NA))
dat_imputed<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),b6=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3))
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by id, fill values downwards, then fill upwards. I think this is what you need.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(b6, .direction = "down") %>% 
  fill(b6, .direction = "up")
```

Comment: I think you could also do `.direction = "downup"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `approxfun` to add missing values inside `ave` for grouping like:

```
dat$b6 <- ave(dat$b6, dat$id, FUN=function(x)
   approxfun(x, method = "constant", rule=2)(seq_along(x)))
identical(dat, dat_imputed)
#[1] TRUE
```